# Dynamically decide which class to inject in Guice

Tags: java, guice

I have a question regarding Guice. I have got an interface IMyInterface, the class MyClass implements it.

```
public class MyClass {
   public MyClass(IMyWorker);
}
```

The interface IMyWorker has two implementaters MyWorker1 and MyWorker2.

The binding I have got is:

```
    bind(IMyInterface.class).to(MyClass.class);
    bind(IMyWorker.class).annotatedWith(W1.class).to(MyWorker1.class);
    bind(IMyWorker.class).annotatedWith(W2.class).to(MyWorker2.class);
```

W1 and W2 are defined annotations.

My questions is that: When I create an instance of MyClass, how can I specify which Worker I want to inject into the constructor of MyClass?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the annotation to the constructor of `MyClass`.

```
@Inject
public MyClass(@W1 IMyWorker worker) 
{
    ....
}
```

This way an instance of class `MyWorker1` will be injected.